# How can I list the undocumented modules/classes/constants/methods with rdoc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation, rdoc

I have a Rails app that I am documenting with RDOC. When I run the rake rdoc command, it tells me:

```
  Classes:     96 (  6 undocumented)
  Modules:     22 ( 14 undocumented)
  Constants:   12 ( 11 undocumented)
  Attributes:  27 ( 27 undocumented)
  Methods:    545 (532 undocumented)

  Total:      702 (590 undocumented)
  15.95% documented
```

I want to find the undocumented classes, modules, constant and methods, so I want it to simply list the undocumented items. Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `rdoc` as its own command you can specify various options.

In your case you're looking for `rdoc -C` which is short for "coverage report".

`rdoc -h` will list all of the command-line options.

Comment: For my Rails project I had to modify the Rake task and add the -C option.   Something like: rdoc.options << "-C"